# python3: how to use the press Ctrl+X (cut) and Ctrl+V using pynput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, key, copy-paste

following [pynput documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput) I tried this to "cut":

1: select some text in an editor

2: run this_code.py using a shortcut (without leaving the active windows)

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
    keyboard.press('x')
    keyboard.release('x')
```

The python console open actually print: ^X. The combination of keys are right but it doesn't do what it's suppose to do: cut the selected text store it in the clipboard. *(I'm not interested to just store the clipboard content in a variable, I want a Ctrl+C)*

I guess this answser will also solve the remaining part: Ctrl+V (to past some data which will be first inserted in the clipboard)

Answer (score 6):

I took 3  things into consideration:

- since I am on a mac, the combination is Command+X instead of Ctrl+X
- I can only make it work if I use keyboard.press (pressed doesn't work for me, don't know why)
- For the special keys, I have to use their Key.value (so, Key.ctrl becomes Key.ctrl.value; Key.Shift becomes Key.Shift.value...)

In the end, this worked for me:

```
# I tested this code as it is in Mac OS
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

# keyboard.press(Key.ctrl.value) #this would be for your key combination
keyboard.press(Key.cmd.value)
keyboard.press('x')
keyboard.release('x')
# keyboard.release(Key.ctrl.value) #this would be for your key combination
keyboard.release(Key.cmd.value)
```

> Even though this question is a bit old, I was having this same problem and found a solution that worked for me. Might come in handy for someone in the future.

Comment: How could you select the text?

Answer (score 2):

First install pyautogui with:
`pip install pyautogui`

#Then in your code write:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Comment: I believe the OP specifically wanted `pynput`, not `pyautogui`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `keyboard.type(msg)` instead of `keyboard.press(key)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my side, and I think the problem is that you are using `Key.ctrl` as the argument for `keyboard.pressed()` on line 3.

Instead of that you should be using `Key.ctrl.value`.

So, the correct version of the code you have given would be:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl.value):
    keyboard.press('x')
    keyboard.release('x')
```