# Not able to select text in pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I'm writing a python script using `pynput` library, in which I want to select the text of particular length.

For that I'm first pressing shift and then pressing multiple times left arrow key. So that the text left to the cursor id selected and can be further used for copying purpose.

Here is my code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard_controller = Controller()
with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.shift_l):
    keyboard_controller.press(keyboard.Key.left)
    keyboard_controller.release(keyboard.Key.left)
    keyboard_controller.press(keyboard.Key.left)
    keyboard_controller.release(keyboard.Key.left)
    keyboard_controller.press(keyboard.Key.left)
    keyboard_controller.release(keyboard.Key.left)
```

This moves my cursor to left by 3 steps but even if the shift is pressed, the text is not getting selected. What I'm missing here?

**Edit:**

> OS: Windows 10
>
> Environment: Python 3.6.5

Here is demo of what is happening in my vs code.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard = Controller()
```

**Option 1:**

```
with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
    keyboard.press(Key.left)
    keyboard.release(Key.left)
    keyboard.press(Key.left)
    keyboard.release(Key.left)
```

**Option 2:**

```
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.left)
keyboard.release(Key.left)
keyboard.press(Key.left)
keyboard.release(Key.left)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)
```

**Option 3:**

```
keyboard.press(Key.shift.value)
keyboard.press(Key.left.value)
keyboard.release(Key.left.value)
keyboard.press(Key.left.value)
keyboard.release(Key.left.value)
keyboard.release(Key.shift.value)
```

Here is video proof it works on my machine :)

[image]

Comment: Not working. What is the difference between those two? I think no difference at all.

Comment: According to the docs: "Only the generic modifiers will be set; when pressing either Key.shift_l, Key.shift_r or Key.shift, only Key.shift will be present." so my idea was that Controller does not see Key.shift_l status and I used generic Key.shift instead. Not working either though...

Comment: One interesting behavior is that if you type something when shift is pressed (`keyboard.type('abc')` inside `with` statement), it is getting changed to upper case letters. So I don't understand why selection is not working.

Comment: Check this interesting answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743087/python3-how-to-use-the-press-ctrlx-cut-and-ctrlv-using-pynput
Maybe it will help anyhow?

Comment: Thanks for providing link and updating answer, but unfortunately none of the above options are working. They just move cursor to left. I've also tried shift with value and left key without value option but still not working.

Comment: May I suggest that you update your question with environment details? OS, tools you use, etc? Today I have tried the code and it worked perfectly. The only thing - I had to place cursor manually with mouse button click. Maybe you need to position your cursor?

Comment: Yes, I'm positioning my cursor manually on the text which I want to select. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: @Kaushal28, I have a feeling that your text is already selected, that's why you don't see the selection being done by pynput controller. Don't you think so?

Comment: Try to put your cursor at the end of any other string in your code/text before running the code.

Comment: No I'm sure the text is not selected already. I think why you feel this is because the word is highlighted by vs code and is not selected. Selected text would have blue color same as your picture

Comment: Well, since package seems to be working as expected, I can't think of anything else I can help you with. Just again - test it on some other string... ;)

Comment: No problem! Thanks for your time and help! I've raised issue on github. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've just toyed around with pynput and pyautogui and finally found a combination using pynput that will complete this shift hotkey function. I was using page_down rather than arrow keys for my code but I confirmed that both work. For some reason if you press down both the shift key and shift_r key, you are able to highlight text by moving the cursor.

Setup:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
```

Code:

```
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.shift_r)
keyboard.press(Key.page_down)  # or keyboard.press(Key.left)
keyboard.release(Key.page_down)  # or keyboard.release(Key.left)
keyboard.release(Key.shift_r)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)
```